# How to find the Grafana version that was used to export JSON?

Tags: grafana

I have a JSON that can be imported for grafana dashboard. I'd like to know in which version it was exported. The "schemaVersion" doesn't give the exact the grafana version. Anyway I can find the exact grafana version used for exporting?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `__requires` list, where Grafana version is available:

```
"__requires": [
...
  {
    "type": "grafana",
    "id": "grafana",
    "name": "Grafana",
    "version": "5.2.4"
  },
 ...
```